# Catching TAB key press with keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to archieve 2 objectives but I archive one at time, never both of them.
First I have an input field that should fires an event when a key is pressed and I  need to catch the field value. I use letters, number and the TAB key. So if I use keyup it fires at the first char. If I use keydown it takes 2 char to fire because when it fires the first time the char is not pressed yet. So when I press for the second time it fires with the first letter and so on.

Said that, it is clear that what I need is the keyup event that put the value in the field then the event is fired. But TAB has a special meaning in my case and it is not the default behavior and with TAB key I am unable to catch e.which, e.charCode nor e.keyCode! Only with keydown I am able to get those value!

Now I don´t have a clue what to do. How could I catch TAB key or make keydown catch the value of a field?

P.S keypress also working as keydown. Event is fired before I have the value in the field

**EDIT 1:**
Here is the code:

```
$('input[data-action="keyupNome"]').each(function () {          
        $(this).on("keypress", function(e) {    

            //Se o campo não estiver vazio
            if($(this).val() != '') {               

                if(key != 9)  // the tab key code
                {                                                               
                    limpaCamposBusca('nome');

                    var width  = $('#nomeBusca').width();
                    $('.nomeContainer').css('width', width);            
                    $('.displayNomeTbl').css('width', width);

                    buscaEndereco('Controller/Dispatcher.php?classe=Buscas&acao=buscaEnderecoPorNome', 'nome');     

                }//if key == 9
                else {
                    alert('here');
                    e.preventDefault();
                }       
            }// val == ''   
            else {                  
                clearFields();
                clearBuscaCliente();
                reactivateFields();
            }       

        }); 
    });
```

Comment: We like to see code. Can you share a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just edited the question with the code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The trick is to use `keydown` and to combine actual value of the field with the char currently pressed OR to catch TAB in `keydown` and set an external variable to be used in `keyup` as in my example.

EDIT :
In fact, I realized that not preventing default behavior of TAB in keydown doesn't fire keyup. So, no variable is needed, but only preventing TAB on keydown. Anyhow, this version always work if the glitch you talked about exist in some circumstances.

```js
(function() {

var tabKeyPressed = false;

$("#t").keydown(function(e) {
   tabKeyPressed = e.keyCode == 9;
   if (tabKeyPressed) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
   }
});

$("#t").keyup(function(e) {
   if (tabKeyPressed) {
      $(this).val("TAB"); // Do stuff for TAB
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
   }

   //Do other stuff when not TAB
});

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="t" value="">
```